# How to convert date/time format from yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z to yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I pulled delivery date/times from easypost api using apps scripts. When I write the date/time to the sheet, it is in the wrong format. It's yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z and it says it's text not a date. I need help either running a script to make the change after the data hits the sheet. Can anyone please help?

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    activeSheet.getRange(i, 26).setValue(parsed.status);

if (parsed.status == 'delivered'){
  var deliveredEvents = parsed.tracking_details.filter(function (el) {
    return el.status == 'delivered';
  });

  if (deliveredEvents.length == 1) {
    activeSheet.getRange(i, 22).setValue(deliveredEvents[0].datetime);
```

Here's how the dates look in the sheet:

Deliver Date
2022-03-18T16:03:42Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date string is in a format that the constructor recognizes then:

```
activeSheet.getRange(i, 22).setValue(new Date(deliveredEvents[0])).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If it doesn't recongize it the you may have to extract fullYear,month, and date and create the Date() object yourself.  You don't really format the date you can format the way the spreadsheet represents it or you can post it as a string in which case it's no long a Date() object

based upon your example:

```
let t = "1969-12-31".split('-');
let dt = new Date(t[0],t[1]-1,t[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It didn't recognize it because it came to the sheet as 1969-12-31. I am newer to coding so I am not sure how to do the second option. I will do some more research to find out how to do what you mentioned. Thanks, again!

Comment: It actually worked with the following code: activeSheet.getRange(i, 22).setValue(new Date(deliveredEvents[0].datetime));

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google sheets, I would recommend just using cell functions to split out the date/time as you want rather than using an app script.

I spit the cell first by doing `=SPLIT(A1,"T","")` which gave me two cells, one with the data and one with the time(+"Z"). You can easily remove the Z using the same method. Just be aware that the Z represents UTC time, so the time stamp that EasyPost is giving you is considered to be UTC time.

[image: Screen Capture]

Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17fl5_KHkc9JuEO1eHe_DQIjo32JxNlqKnTC8yTvV0Vg/edit?usp=sharing